# How to refresh data in sql table and C# windows for DataGrideView?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I'm writing a C# windows form application linked with SQL database tables, in widows form. I add a dataGridView to my form and added a table of database to it, when I run the program it show data fine. now I added a delete button to delete the selected sell row's, but when I use this button database table not change. but when I stop program and rerun it again I see that the row was deleted. now I want to know if there is a way to affect this action immediately in database table.
this is my code:

```
private void btnDeleteUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Username= dataGridView1[0,dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        using (FrmLogin.connection1 = new SqlConnection(FrmLogin.conectionString))
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Users Where UserName='" + Username + "' ", FrmLogin.connection1))
        {
            FrmLogin.connection1.Open();
            sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            FrmLogin.connection1.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Deleted");
        }
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex);
    }
```

first run image:
[image: first run image]

delete a row:
[image: delete a row]

now I log out without stop and log in the form again. and delete row is in

[image: data table]

now if I stop the program an rerun it deleted row doesn't exist.
[image: deleted row doesn't exist]

thank you if you can help me about it.

Comment: How are you setting the DataGridView source? After deleting, just call Refresh method or set the DataSource again.

Comment: well i drag the data table to DataGridView in design mode. and im new to sql and dont know how to change data source. but in youtube there are many video that they didnt reset DataSource, and i used DataGridView.Refresh() and no change hapened!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask this in MSDN and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/935026/how-to-refresh-datagridview-table-from-sql-data-ta.html) is answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think that reloading data from database after deleting will be the best way
or try to use

```
dataGridView1.Update();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: I do this before i ask my question but data changed only after i stop the program and run it again.